# Concatenating temp files in to a single file in tcl

Tags: file-io, tcl, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate all the temporary files in a folder in to a single text file. But I keep running in to errors:

```
 if { [catch { exec cat /tmp/new_temp/* >> /tmp/full_temp.txt } msg] }
```

Error Message:

```
-cat: /tmp/new_temp/*: No such file or directory
```

If I try the same thing on tclsh (without the catch, and exec) it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why such a terrible approach?  Use Tcl itself to concatenate those files:

```
set out [open /tmp/full_temp.txt w]
fconfigure $out -translation binary
foreach fname [glob -nocomplain -type f "/tmp/new_temp/*"] {
    set in [open $fname]
    fconfigure $in -translation binary
    fcopy $in $out
    close $in
}
close $out
```

Comment: What is the -type argument to glob supposed to do here? I get an error when I include that (/bad argument to "-types": -f)

It seems to work fine if I remove the "-type f"

Comment: @egorulz, [it selects only files](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/glob.htm#M10) from everything which matched.  Otherwise you'd need to do `file stat` on each matched entry and see if it's really a file and not a directory or a socket or a fifo. This is needed because attempting to `fcopy` a directory will fail with an error, and attempting to do this with a socket or a fifo might just try to read data from them which supposedly is just wrong).  Note that your original attempt with `cat` is prone to the same problem.

Comment: @egorulz, of course, if you're sure you are in *full* control of the `/tmp/new_temp`'s contents, you could carry on without the check, but at least you should be aware of potential problems. And a correction to my first comment: it's `open` which will fail for directories, not `fcopy`.

Comment: @egorulz, as to why passing `glob` the `-types` swich gives you an error -- supposedly you have old like dirt Tcl, like pre-8.4 or even older.  Personally, I do not even remember time when `glob` did not support this option.  Or you might have some non-standard Tcl build (?)

Comment: @kostix Thanks for the explanation. I'm using version 8.4 so that might be why it gives that error. Yes, it's pre historic I know, a newer version would help me to start working on threads and other stuff.

I'm creating the temp folder in question and deleting it after each run so there should not be any unexpected folders in it.

Comment: @egorulz, I think I see why it failed for you: to select files, pass `f` to `-types`, not `-f` like you did. This is the value for the `-types` option, not an option by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Because Tcl is not the shell, it does not automatically expand the glob pattern. Try

```
if { [catch {exec sh -c {cat /tmp/new_temp/* >> /tmp/full_temp.txt}} msg] }
```

To get Tcl to do filename expansion, you need the `glob` command

```
set code [catch [list exec cat {*}[glob /tmp/new_temp/*] >> /tmp/full_temp.txt] msg]
if {$code != 0} {
    # handle error
}
```

Comment: The second example is incorrect as it misses the `cat` itself. I would also stress that this case is that *rare* one in which the `glob`'s default behaviour -- blow up if no file matched -- is actually the right thing, otherwise `cat` would try to read from the process's `stdin`. I mean, usually it's advisable to pass `-nocomplain` to `glob`, but this case is different.

Comment: oops missed it. I took another kick at the cat